# Which class should the Combiner be inherited from (or extend) in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, combiners

In Hadoop, the mapper and reducer classes should extend the Mapper or Reducer interface. However, I could not find the interface which the combiner class should extend. What is the signature for the combiner class in Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

A combiner extends the `Reducer` interface, and its signature should emit the same Key / Value types as it consumes, for example the Word Count combiner has the following signatures (for the new `o.a.h.mapreduce` and old `o.a.h.mapred` packages):

```
public class MyCombinerNewApi 
    extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

}

public class MyCombinerOldApi 
    implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

}
```

It is sometimes common for the Combiner class to be the same as the Reducer class (as in the Word Count example).

Some nice links explaining Combiners in more detail:

- Phillipe Adjimun's blog on ["To use or not to use a combiner"](http://www.philippeadjiman.com/blog/2010/01/14/hadoop-tutorial-series-issue-4-to-use-or-not-to-use-a-combiner/)
- [Pro Hadoop Book - Combiners](http://books.google.com/books?id=H3mvcxPeUfwC&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=hadoop%20word%20count%20combiner&source=bl&ots=pXuOsc2Ft9&sig=z1Inyd819v9yw-8nkVXJU2RL-50&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WKDnUOPaG6jy0wGs4ICgBw&ved=0CHYQ6AEwCA)

Comment: +1 , I found another small but good article on combiners here : http://bigdataspeak.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/what-are-combiners-in-hadoop/

Answer (score 0):

Combiners is mini- Reducer . They follow the same signature of Reducer itself

```
public class Combiner extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
```